# Problem with If statement

Tags: conditional

It is a very simple problem but I am confused. A comment is required.
I have the following list

```
masters={C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
 C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]}
```

Now if I write

```
If [C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] == masters[[2]], 
 Print["Yes"], Print["No"]]
```

It should give `No` , but it is giving

```
If[C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] == 
  C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0], Print["Yes"], Print["No"]]
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 7):

```
masters = {C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
   C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]};
```

`C18` is an undefined function. Since neither expression evaluates, it is unknown whether the expressions are [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)

```
If[C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] == masters[[2]], Print["Yes"], 
 Print["No"], Print["Unknown"]]

(* Unknown *)
```

Use [`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) to check whether the unevaluated expressions are identical.

```
If[C18[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0] === masters[[2]], Print["Yes"], 
 Print["No"], Print["Unknown"]]

(* No *)
```